# How to catch CheckInvalidPathChars() exception

Tags: c#, exception, umbraco

I get an automatic exception from the `CheckInvalidPathChars()` method when I put an invalid character like `<`, `>`  in the url.

The path is checked automatically and I'd like to catch the exception in order to redirect the user to the `404 error` page.

How can I catch that exception?

Relevant info:
I'm using `Umbraco 4.9.0`

---

The **solution** I found:

I created the file Global.asax in the root of the project. This file has, among others, the method "Application_Error", which fires when there is an illegal character in the URL.

I edited this method with the following code:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        string errorTemplate = library.RenderTemplate(nodeId);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", errorTemplate.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(errorTemplate);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is quite straight forward - don't put invalid characters in the URL :-)

But seriously, instead of trying to catch the error, try and prevent those characters getting into your URLs. Encode the characters if they are generated by your code, or alternatively in the `config/umbracoSettings.config` file there is a section where you can specify what characters to exclude from the path that Umbraco creates from the page title.

I almost always add extra characters to the default values. This ensures that when you publish a page, any invalid characters are stripped from the URL path.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot control what users type on their browsers ;)
The solution I found was to use the Global.asax.cs with the Application_Error method, which fires when the path has illegal characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a try-catch block for it:

```
try
{
    // code that could throw the exception - probably when you call the CheckInvalidPathChars() method
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // exception code
}
```

Over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177444/2402338 you can find an answer on how to catch a specific exception.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the problem properly. I know with try/catch I can control an exception. The problem is that Umbraco is executing CheckInvalidPathChars() somewhere, and I have no way to put a try/catch there. How can I control that in this case?

Comment: I think the place to look is not in Umbraco code. It sounds to me like ASP.NET is running this method. I took a gander through the Umbraco 4.9.0 source code and a search in VS revealed nothing for CheckInvalidPatchChars(). Maybe the following question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082662/how-to-redirect-404-bad-urls-to-the-homepage

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the idea to use the global.asax.cs  with the Application_Error method! :)

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction! If you found a solution, go ahead and add it here for others that might have the same question! :)